# Problems porting formula from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, math, formula

I've been tasked with porting a small internal company formula/algorithm from Java to PHP, and have for the most part been successful, but am clearly going wrong somewhere because I'm not getting the same output from my ported version than I am from the PHP version. I'm relatively new to PHP and don't know anything about Java, so I'm guessing I'm missing a subtle but crucial difference in how the two languages do maths, particularly on the line with the `double` and `floor()` function.

Here is the original Java code, which needs to take user input in the format `F999` and generate a four-digit output:

```
String input;

String Generate() {
    int charAt = (((this.input.charAt(0) * 5) * 2) - 698) + this.input.charAt(1);
    int charAt2 = ((((this.input.charAt(2) * 5) * 2) + charAt) + this.input.charAt(3)) - 528;
    charAt2 = ((charAt2 << 3) - charAt2) % 100;
    String valueOf = String.valueOf((((((259 % charAt) % 100) * 5) * 5) * 4) + ((((charAt2 % 10) * 5) * 2) + ((int) Math.floor((double) (charAt2 / 10)))));
    return valueOf.length() == 3 ? "0" + valueOf : valueOf.length() == 2 ? "00" + valueOf : valueOf.length() == 1 ? "000" + valueOf : valueOf;
}
```

And here is my ported PHP version of it, currently simulating user input using a string:

```
$input = "F999"; # should output 2360

$charAt = ((((int) $input[0] * 5) * 2) - 698) + $input[1];
$charAt2 = (((($input[2] * 5) * 2) + $charAt) + $input[3]) - 528;
$charAt2 = (($charAt2 << 3) - $charAt2) % 100;
$valueOf = strval(((((((259 % $charAt) % 100) * 5) * 5) * 4) + (((($charAt2 % 10) * 5) * 2) + ((int) floor((double) ($charAt2 / 10))))));
if (strlen($valueOf) == 3) $valueOf = '0' . $valueOf;
elseif (strlen($valueOf) == 2) $valueOf = '00' . $valueOf;
elseif (strlen($valueOf) == 1) $valueOf = '000' . $valueOf;
return $valueOf; # currently outputs 5837
```

What does the Java source have that my PHP code is missing?

Comment: Don't try to fix the whole thing at once. Launch your step debugger on both and figure out where they start diverging. You can temporarily hard-code the parts that are identical. In any case, `(int)'F'` is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following difference:

- In Java String operation `charAt` returns result as an integer type `char`, which is an unsigned integer from 0 to 65535.
- In PHP string indexing operation `[]` returns result as a character.

Thus, in Java `this.input.charAt(0)` returns an ASCII code of 'F', i.e. 70.
In PHP `$input[0]` returns a character 'F', which cannot be converted directly to int. So, in PHP `(int)('F')` is just 0. In order to get an ASCII code of a symbol in PHP use `ord()`. For example:

```
$input = "F999"; # should output 2360

$charAt = (((ord($input[0]) * 5) * 2) - 698) + ord($input[1]);
$charAt2 = ((((ord($input[2]) * 5) * 2) + $charAt) + ord($input[3])) - 528;
$charAt2 = (($charAt2 << 3) - $charAt2) % 100;
$valueOf = strval(((((((259 % $charAt) % 100) * 5) * 5) * 4) + (((($charAt2 % 10) * 5) * 2) + ((int) floor((double) ($charAt2 / 10))))));
if (strlen($valueOf) == 3) $valueOf = '0' . $valueOf;
elseif (strlen($valueOf) == 2) $valueOf = '00' . $valueOf;
elseif (strlen($valueOf) == 1) $valueOf = '000' . $valueOf;
return $valueOf;
```

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7eb5417e8eea41ba7d8b9137690542517eedd3cc) is a demo.

Comment: Damn, I'm impressed at how fast you figured this out. So the original code is actually returning the ASCII representation of the character? Do you know if this is a common approach when needing to generate numbers like this?

Comment: A subtle difference is that PHP strings are purely binary (they don't have encoding information) and `ord()` operates on bytes rather than characters. So this works as long as you save your PHP files with an ASCII-compatible encoding (such as UTF-8) and you don't get characters outside the ASCII range.